# Sending a request with a NodeMCU when a key is pressed

Tags: arduino-ide, wifi, nodemcu

I want to send a request to a server with the GET method with URL parameters when a key is pressed on the NodeMCU. But I can't get this to work; I get the below error in the serial monitor:

```
 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,7)

wdt reset
load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0x2d
csum 0x2d
v951aeffa
~ld
```

My main code:

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h> 

const char* ssid = "MobinNet1365"; 
const char* password = "G12229M1Q64"; 
const char* host = "webhook.site";

const int button = 8;
int temp = 0;

void setup() { 
  Serial.begin(115200); 
  pinMode(button, INPUT);
  delay(10);
  Serial.println(); 
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected"); 
  Serial.println("IP address: "); 
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP()); 
} 

void loop() {
  temp = digitalRead(button);  
  if (temp == HIGH) {       
    Serial.println(host);
    WiFiClient client;
    const int httpPort = 80;
    
    String url = "/df35c8cd-0398-4c92-b55f-b9e36629b309";
    url += "?switche=";
    url += "1";  
       
    client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" + "Host: " + host + "\r\n" + "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");      
  }
}
```

My request sending code is below:

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "your-ssid";
const char* password = "your-password";
const char* host = "";

void setup() { 
    Serial.begin(115200); 
    delay(10); 
    Serial.println(); 
    Serial.print("Connecting to ");
    Serial.println(ssid);   
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      delay(500);
      Serial.print(".");
    }

    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("WiFi connected");
    Serial.println("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

int value = 0;

void loop() { 
  delay(5000);
  ++value;
  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(host);
  WiFiClient client;
  const int httpPort = 80;
  if (!client.connect(host, httpPort)) {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }

  String url = "/";
  /* url += "?param1=";
  url += param1;
  url += "?param2=";
  url += param2;
  */
  Serial.print("Requesting URL: ");
  Serial.println(url);
  client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" + "Host: " + host + "\r\n" + "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
  unsigned long timeout = millis();
  while (client.available() == 0) {
    if (millis() - timeout > 5000) {
      Serial.println(">>> Client Timeout !");
      client.stop(); 
      return;
    } 
  }

  while (client.available()) {
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    Serial.print(line);
  }
    
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("closing connection"); 
}
```

And my key press detector code is below:

```cpp
const int button = 8;
int temp = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(button, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  temp = digitalRead(button);
     
  if (temp == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("LED Turned ON");
    delay(1500);
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("LED Turned OFF");
    delay(1500);
  }
}
```

My circuit is:

NodeMcu => MicroSwitch

VIN => C

D0 => NO

G => 10k => NO

How can I make it so that when the key is pressed it sends a request?

Comment: I don't quite understand--what is ypur actual code? One chunk of code never initializes "host", another does. What is the actual code that causes the error? Are you making a request between two NodeMCUs?

Comment: No its just for sending a request to a server when a key pressed but i get "ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,7)

wdt reset
load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0x2d
csum 0x2d
v951aeffa
~ld" error and that code has header named main code is my actual code

Comment: Please include only the relevant code.

Comment: why do you believe that the `ets Jan 8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,7) ....` message is an error message?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, some consideration :

1. const int button = 8;
   const int button = 5; // CHANGE TO Pin "D1 GPIO5"

GPIO8 is used to connect the flash chip, you may change to Pin "D1" which is GPIO 5.

- Check with your board's pinout.

2. to prevent non-stop keep calling within in the loop, you may use millis();

for example :

```
void GetUrl() {
    temp = digitalRead(button);  
  if (temp == HIGH) {       
    Serial.println(host);
    WiFiClient client;
    const int httpPort = 80;
    
    String url = "/df35c8cd-0398-4c92-b55f-b9e36629b309";
    url += "?switche=";
    url += "1";  

    String link = String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" + "Host: " + host + "\r\n" + "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
//    Serial.println( "link : " + link );
    client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" + "Host: " + host + "\r\n" + "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");      
  }
}


unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long interval = 1000 * 0.5; // 500ms (0.5 sec)

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    GetUrl();
  }
}
```

Reference :

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/BlinkWithoutDelay

https://iotbyhvm.ooo/gpio-pins-esp8266/